# Why are < , ( and [ symbols used in asm

Tags: assembly

Could someone please explain what does using %< mean in asm
The instruction that i am trying to understand is "%(%<%[%|sync\n"

I understand that ( is used for referencing to memory location.
But cant understand usage of < and [ symbols.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like no assembly language instruction I've ever encountered. What assembler, what platform?

Comment: That is not a proper assembler instruction in any instruction set I ever seen!

Comment: It looks vaguely like something io_x would write in his personal assembly dialect.. other than that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

`"%(%<%[%|sync\n"` is not a valid instruction in any language. However, on the off chance that this is a garbled version of some real question, let's talk about `%[`...

The syntax `%[foo]` is used in [GNU-style extended inline assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5) to refer to a "named operand". For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int cvar = 42;
    asm("incl %[name]"
        : [name] "=r" (cvar)
        : "0" (cvar));
    printf("cvar is %d\n", cvar);  // prints "cvar is 43"
}
```

That line of assembly is exactly equivalent to

```
    asm("incl %0"
        : "=r" (cvar)
        : "0" (cvar));
```

It's just a bit more readable, in the case where the `asm` block starts getting complicated.

As for `%<`, `%(`, and `%|`, I'm not aware of any assembly language that assigns meanings to those. And as for the various processor instructions named `sync`, you can look up `sync` in any reference manual for MIPS, PowerPC, or whatever processor you're programming for.